# How to install perl modules on Windows?

Tags: perl

I downloaded some perl modules from CPAN. Usually, we take the 2 steps below to install it.

```
perl Makefile.PL
make install
```

But this doesn't work on Windows.

I am using ActivePerl, what should I do to install 3rd party modules?

I managed to run the 2 commands below:

```
perl Makefile.PL
nmake install
```

And I see **FAQ.pod** and **XXX.pm** being copied to some folder. But question is, I saw these 2 files exist before i run any command. They are just in the downloaded zip file. So why do I still need to run the make commands?

Comment: http://www.activestate.com/blog/2010/10/how-install-cpan-modules-activeperl

Comment: what perl interpreter are you using?

Comment: I am using ActivePerl 5.16.0 for Windows.

Comment: Luckily I got the answer before my question got closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So why do I still need to run the make commands?

Most of what an installer does (for a Perl module or otherwise), is copying files. That doesn't mean it's all it does. To name a few others:

- Obtaining installation options from the user.
- Checking for missing dependencies.
- Installing missing dependencies.
- Determining the correct directories into which to install files.
- Configuring the module for the particular system or build of Perl.
- Generating derived files.

  - Compiling C (XS) components.
  - Generating documentation.
  - Making bundled Perl scripts self-executing.
- Running tests.
- Setting permissions.
- etc

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you need to go out to Microsoft and download the nmake executable so you'll have a "make" to run.  But I recall a GUI PPM client that should help you a little too.

When I used to use activestate, I used PPM and then used CPAN when PPM didn't have the module I needed.  In this way, I was able to get Catalyst and DBIx::Class installed and working on a windows box, using Mysql locally and SQL server for remote data warehouse queries, circa 2007.

It took a little more effort than a Unix installation, but sometimes we don't get to choose our OS.

Answer (score 1):

```
 make install
```

also runs the tests, which is good because not every CPAN module is tested against windows, by its author. I know that I don't.

Secondly make install updates perllocal.pod, which tracks the installation of CPAN packages. You can look in there:

```
 perldoc perllocal
```

and see all the packages that have been installed on your machine via CPAN.

If you don't see a need for the package manager, and you're using a pure perl module, then by all means just copy it into place.  We'll keep the black helicopters  in the hangar this time around.

Comment: `make install` does *not* run the tests.

Comment: Since when? install has always had a dependency on test for me.

Comment: Since always. The `test` target is completely optional when installing manually. Check it yourself: `cpanm --look random-dist ; perl Makefile.PL ; ack 'install ::' Makefile ; make -n install`

Comment: and using the cpan client, not the cpanm client, 'install module' implies test which implies get.

Comment: This is why we can't have nice things.